# Como actualizo la cultura usando CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy generando una web con diferentes idiomas, siguiendo [este tutorial](https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/) he aplicado a mi solución sus elementos, para cambiar el idioma he realizado el siguiente elemento:

```js
var langArray = [];
$('.selectImagen option').each(function () {
  var img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
  var text = this.innerText;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var item = '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" value="' + value + '"/><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  langArray.push(item);
})

$('#a').html(langArray);

//Set the button value to the first el of the array
$('.btn-select').html(langArray[0]);
$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'en');

//change button stuff on click
$('#a li').click(function () {
  var img = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
  var value = $(this).find('img').attr('value');
  var text = this.innerText;
  var item = '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  $('.btn-select').html(item);
  $('.btn-select').attr('value', value);
  $(".b").toggle(); 
});

$(".btn-select").click(function () {
  $(".b").toggle();
});
```

```css
.selectImagen {
 display: none;
}

#a {
 padding-left: 0px;
}

 #a img, .btn-select img {
  width: 63px;
 }

 #a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
 }

  #a li:hover {
   background-color: #F4F3F3;
  }

  #a li img {
   margin: 5px;
  }

  #a li span, .btn-select li span {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
  }

/* item list */

.b {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 350px;
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.open {
 display: show !important;
}

.btn-select {
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 350px;
 height: 54px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

 .btn-select li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 }

 .btn-select:hover li {
  margin-left: 0px;
 }

 .btn-select:hover {
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
 }

 .btn-select:focus {
  outline: none;
 }

.lang-select {
 margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectImagen">
  <option data-thumbnail="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/portugal/flag-800.png">
    Português
  </option>
  <option data-thumbnail="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-800.png">
    Español
  </option>
</select>

<div class="lang-select">
  <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
  <div class="b">
    <ul id="a"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este me lleva a la función en el controlador para transformar el idioma, pero en mi web solo se visualiza el Español

**Controlador**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }
```

Dispongo de todos los elementos del [Tutorial](https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/)(Resources, CultureHelper, etc.) y al ejecutar la web me realiza correctamente la recogida de strings de Resources al idioma por defecto(Español), pero aunque pulse en el idioma y pase por la función `SetCulture` conserva el idioma por defecto.

**¿Como actualizo la cultura para que pinte en el idioma seleccionado?**

Comment: estas seteando el CultureInfo en el thread?

Comment: @RamiroBarone si, tengo un controlador(BaseController en el tutorial) que lo realiza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los problemas que surgían eran por dos motivos, el primero me faltaba la herencia a la clase `BaseController` el cual en c# se realiza del la siguiente manera:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController //Herencia
{
    // GET: /Home/Index/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

El siguiente problema era que la cookie era segura pero corría en en inseguro como explico en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/364399/101499).