# Creo una cookie pero no se guarda

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy creando una cookie para guardar la cultura y así poder realizar una web internacionalizada. Dispongo de un controlador HomeController que tiene una herencia con otro llamado BaseController que establece el idioma según el texto recuperado de la cookie, pero en el momento de ejecutar la secuencia, pasa por el método que genera la cookie pero en BaseController, al recuperarla da null, en la depuracion del DevOps me muestra que no existe ninguna cookie.

> **Problema derivado de [Como actualizo la cultura usando CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363784/como-actualizo-la-cultura-usando-culturehelper-getimplementedculture)**

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = null;
        // Obtengo la cookie
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
        cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? Request.UserLanguages[0] : null; // obtengo los lenguajes aceptados

        // Valido el nombre de la cultura
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

        // Modifico el hilo con la nueva cultura          
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }

}
```

**HomeController**

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController //Herencia de BaseController
{
    // GET: /Home/Index/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [TsVisible]
    public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        // Valido la cultura
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
        // Obtengo la cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Value = culture;   // Si no es nula la sobreescribo
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Si es nula genero una nueva
            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }
}
```

En teoría con esto generaría la cookie pero no lo hace. He realizado diferentes puntos de parada en el código para monitorear si realiza correctamente la ejecución de la secuencia, la realiza correctamente pero no genera la cookie, dejo algunas capturas en las paradas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **¿Por qué ocurre esto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `Secure` de la cookie limita su utilización a conexiones seguras HTTPS, entonces dejaba dos opciones:

**Menos recomendable**

Eliminar la propiedad [Secure](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.secure?view=netcore-3.1)

**Recomendable**

En la configuración del IIS Express:

- Convertir la propiedad `SSL Enabled` a True.
- Cambiar la propiedad `SSL Url` a `https://localhost:[PUERTO]/`